# Typescript, how to handle spread operators inside interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I currently have a react component that looks like this - notice the spread operator which operates on ...other and is passed on further down the component.

```
interface ButtonProps {
  colourMode: string;
  regular: boolean;
  buttonText: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
  iconSize?: string;
  iconLeft?: React.ReactNode;
  iconRight?: React.ReactNode;
}

const LowProButton = (props: ButtonProps) => {
  const {
    colourMode,
    buttonText,
    disabled,
    iconSize,
    iconLeft,
    iconRight,
    ...other
  } = props;
```

When I try to pass any additional parameter to this button i.e: the onClick in the consumer, it complains that the props are not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ButtonProps' - how do I fix the interface to allow any prop to be passed safely through whilst keeping the strongly typed elements within the interface? To be clear, I want to pass any prop I want to the component, i.e. the onClick or anything else I wish, whilst keeping the colourMode: string etc.

```
<LowProButton
        iconSize="14"
        regular={false}
        iconLeft={<RestartAltIcon />}
        colourMode="secondary"
        buttonText="Detailed"
        onClick={props.performClick}
      ></LowProButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you want to achieve with `other`?
If you want to have all the usual html button properties you then need to extend your interface to allow it so something like

```
interface ButtonProps extends HTMLButtonElement {
  colourMode: string;
  regular: boolean;
  buttonText: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
  iconSize?: string;
  iconLeft?: React.ReactNode;
  iconRight?: React.ReactNode;
}
```